# How do I prevent SQL injection when using the LIKE operator?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sql-injection, node-mysql

I am building a website using Node and the [**node-mysql**](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/) package.

```
app.get('/api/tags', function(req, res) {
  var term = req.query.term;
  var query =
  'SELECT \
     t.tagName \
   FROM tags t \
   JOIN screencastTags st \
     ON st.tagName = t.tagName \
   JOIN screencasts s \
     ON s.screencastId = st.screencastId \
   WHERE s.status = \'approved\' AND t.tagName LIKE \'%' + term + '%\' \
   GROUP BY t.tagName \
   LIMIT 5';
  connection.queryAsync(query).spread(function(tags) {
    tags = tags.map(function(tag) { return tag.tagName });
    res.send(tags);
  })
})
```

Here I use a value from the query string - `term` - to return a list of tags.

My question is: **How do I prevent against SQL injection when I am using the LIKE operator?**

I tried

```
  var query =
  'SELECT \
     t.tagName \
   FROM tags t \
   JOIN screencastTags st \
     ON st.tagName = t.tagName \
   JOIN screencasts s \
     ON s.screencastId = st.screencastId \
   WHERE s.status = \'approved\' AND t.tagName LIKE \'%' + conneciton.escape(term) + '%\' \
   GROUP BY t.tagName \
   LIMIT 5';
```

But that produces invalid SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try to never build an sql request by concatenation. It indeed always increases the risk of the SQL injection footprint.

A placeholder should work even with the LIKE condition.

```
var sql = '... LIKE ? GROUP BY ...';
connection.query(sql, ['%' + term + '%'], function(err, res) {})
```

A prepared statement would even be better for security concerns. you should read https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#escaping-query-values

Comment: Thank you - I will test this now. I use `?` everywhere else in my application but I thought it would be simpler to inspect in the current form. Also, `?` is not equivalent to a prepared statement.